# How to mount a volume on docker container

Tags: docker-volume

Why is this simple docker command is not mapping volume for me?

```
docker run -dit -v ./home:/home ubuntu bash
```

i have also tried this command and it also didn't work.

```
docker run -dit -v ./home:/var/www/html linode/lamp bash
```

i have seen others mapping volumes like this but it is not working for me. i'm running docker on windows 10 desktop. do i need to create 'home' foler or this command will also create 'home' folder for me.? please help. thank you

Comment: Do you run docker using Hyper-V or the old fashioned way with a virtual machine? Also, have you shared drive that you're mapping with container?

Comment: I run docker using Hyper-V. no i haven't shared folder or dive that i'm mapping and i don't think i need to share drive or folder. i have installed wordpress using docker images by using docker-compose.yml file and -v tag worked. i was able to backup my wp-content folder through volume. it won't work when used with docker command.

Comment: i'm sorry. i was wrong. yes i have shared C dive in docker settings. issue is still there.